# Is it possible to print to pdf a Canvas with other div elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I've been trying to print a chart (canvas) along with the custom title and legend (div elements) to pdf and have been so far unsuccessful.
I got the jspf library as well as html2canvas, but nothing is working.
Here is a code snippet of what i've tried:

```
$('#print-chart-btn-donut').on('click', function () {

var canvas = document.querySelector('#' + chart_name_donut + '_Chart');
var canvas_img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0); //JPEG will not match background color

var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'in', 'letter');
html2canvas(document.getElementById(chart_name_donut + "_Title"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(chart_name_donut + "_LegendContainer"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas2) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                
                doc.addImage(img, 'png', -4.25, 2, 20, 4, 'Doughnut1', 0, 0);
                var img2 = canvas2.toDataURL("image/png");
                doc.addImage(img2, 'png', -4.25, 1.75, 20, 4, 'Doughnut2', 0, 0);
            }
        })
    }
});
doc.addImage(canvas_img, 'png', -4.25, 1.75, 20, 4, 'Doughnut', 0, 0);
doc.autoPrint();
var blob = doc.output("bloburl");
window.open(blob, 'Doughnut Chart', "height=" + window.outerHeight + ", width=" + 0.36 * window.innerWidth + "\"");});
```

Using this code, it generates a pdf with only the original canvas element (canvas_img in this case).
Does anyone know a nice solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to study Javascript callbacks.  The `onrendered` callbacks do not happen immediately, they are executed once the action is completed.

You should move the last 3 lines into the last nested `onrendered` callback.  With this change, the PDF will be generated after the html2canvas rendering has occurred.

```
$('#print-chart-btn-donut').on('click', function() {

    var canvas = document.querySelector('#' + chart_name_donut + '_Chart');
    var canvas_img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0); //JPEG will not match background color

    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'in', 'letter');
    html2canvas(document.getElementById(chart_name_donut + "_Title"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            html2canvas(document.getElementById(chart_name_donut + "_LegendContainer"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas2) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                    doc.addImage(img, 'png', -4.25, 2, 20, 4, 'Doughnut1', 0, 0);
                    var img2 = canvas2.toDataURL("image/png");
                    doc.addImage(img2, 'png', -4.25, 1.75, 20, 4, 'Doughnut2', 0, 0);

                    // Generate the PDF after the final callback has executed
                    doc.autoPrint();
                    var blob = doc.output("bloburl");
                    window.open(blob, 'Doughnut Chart', "height=" + window.outerHeight + ", width=" + 0.36 * window.innerWidth + "\"");
                }
            })
        }
    });
    doc.addImage(canvas_img, 'png', -4.25, 1.75, 20, 4, 'Doughnut', 0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Doing it as you suggested still doesnt work, a new window doesnt even open.. any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Anything in your JS console?

Comment: nope, empty.. in the end i used a different method without html2canvas and printing is working. Thanks for the help anyway!